# What is the process for deleting/merging duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

What is the general procedure for deleting or merging tags that are duplicates/synonyms of other tags?

As I understand, unused tags will get deleted automatically after a period of time.

Where tags should be merged, is there a process where the less established tags get migrated over to the more established tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Moderators can merge synonyms into the parent tag.

Answer (score 0):

*Although this question is answered I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250930/6075112) post on meta.stackoverflow that is also useful. (Credit to Kedarnath)*

---

One way to remove tag is just remove the duplicate tag from all the tagged question (and even replace it with the appropriate tag). After 24 hours all non-used zombie tags get deleted by system.

[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Another way is to post the question on meta and request for the particular tag to be merged or deleted. Moderator/developer will merge/remove it.